# I am trying to figure out a way to update dates in one field based on dates in another field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is what I have:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

If I count rownumbers by Credit_Line_NO and AsOfDate, I can find the max rn per AsOfDate.  I want to make the Next_Payment_Date equal Expiry_Date_Revised.  Then, make each prior Next_Payment_Date go back the number of months in the 'FBNK_MONTHS' field.  Most of the time this is 3, but it could be 1 or 12.

I'm starting off like this:

```
   select 
        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by AsOfDate)
    from 
        TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS
```

I'm not sure what the next step is.  Does any SQL expert here know how to do this?

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Here is my DLL:

```
--DROP TABLE Reporting_Table
CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
    Credit_Line_NO       Varchar(10),
    Next_Payment_Date    Date,
    AsOfDate             Date,
    EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED      Date,
    FBNK_MONTHS           INT
)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3) 
INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, Next_Payment_Date, AsOfDate, EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED, FBNK_MONTHS)
Values('9938810',' 12/31/2017',' 10/31/2017',' 10/4/2018', 3)
```

Perhaps something like the script below, but I keep getting an error about 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS''

```
with cteMain as (
    select 
        *,  rn = row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by AsOfDate) AS sn
    from TBL_FBNK_LIMIT_HIST_TRANS
)
Select m.Credit_Line_NO, 
        m.NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE, 
        m.AsOfDate, 
        m.EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED,
        m.rn, 
        m.FBNK_MONTHS
From cteMain as m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLead
ON sLead.sn = m.sn+1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLeg
ON sLeg.sn = m.sn-1
ORDER BY m.Credit_Line_NO, m.AsOfDate
```

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly. Sample data is best served as DDL+DML.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers, e.g. `Lead` and `Lag`. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version of your query:

```
with cteMain as (
    select 
        *,  row_number() over (partition by Credit_Line_NO order by AsOfDate) as sn
    from Reporting_Table
)
Select m.Credit_Line_NO, 
        sLead.NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE, 
        m.AsOfDate, 
        m.EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED,
        m.sn, 
        m.FBNK_MONTHS
From cteMain as m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLead
ON sLead.sn = m.sn+1
LEFT OUTER JOIN cteMain AS sLeg
ON sLeg.sn = m.sn-1
ORDER BY m.Credit_Line_NO, m.AsOfDate
```

Comment: I think Lead would work, except that I'm on SQL Server 2008.  What is a substitute when using 10-year-old technology?

Comment: here is a great article with options to simulate lag and lead in SQL Server 2008.  [link](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/)

Comment: if the next payment date is just a calculation of expiry_date_revised + 3 months, why not just use a dateadd() function to get the value for it?

Comment: Thanks Jackie.  The query ran, but it didn't produce the results I was after. All NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE records are the same, all AsOfDate records are the same, and all EXPIRY_DATE_REVISED records are the same.

Comment: sorry, didn't notice you weren't using the slead value of next_payment_date in the select.   try now.